# Common Proj for configuration using JPA in Play framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, multi-module

In my project there are 4 modules, and have one common module which will be there in lib of all the modules.

Now, in each module there is a requirement to read configuration from common config db. I want to put in JPA code for this common configuration into common module, which will be accessed from all module.

In common module I have written entity, repository, service and serviceImpl in the common module as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.CONFIGURATION_TABLE, schema = Constants.COMMON_SCHEMA)
public class Configuration
{
     // Columns
}

public interface ConfigurationRepository extends JpaRepository<Configuration, Long>
{
}

public interface ConfigurationServiceI
{
    List<Configuration> getConfigurations();
}

@Named
@Singleton
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationServiceI
{
    @Inject
    private ConfigurationRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Configuration> getConfigurations()
    {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Then, put in the following annotation in Global.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"....repositories", "....common.repositories"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "...", "....common.models", 
        "...common.services", "....common.services.impl"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public static class SpringDataJpaConfiguration
{
      ..... 
}
```

I don't know what is wrong but, I am getting error after running the above project that Configuration Entity is not a managed type.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type:
>   class ....common.models.Configuration
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:142)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:89)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:71)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]\

I have tried same class in single module its working. Can anyone please help me here what needs to be done for common module to work over here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the Hibernate and Spring Data dependencies in the build.sbt of the module where the `common.models.Configuration` is?

Comment: Common module is just getting used as a jar, while in the module I am using it is having those dependencies. When I am putting all classes in that module it is working fine. I am getting error only when I am putting it in common module jar.

Comment: Your component scan did not scan or identify `Configuration` as an entity class. Try other ways like directly listing it in the `persistance.xml` etc.